# Plotting Network Graph

Tags: graph, azure-data-explorer

I have Kusto tables of Vertices + Edges, and want to plot them as a Network Graph.

I tried using Python plugin, but Kusto sandbox only allows tabular output.

Is there any way/hacky way to do so through Kusto Explorer/Kusto Web UI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We are working to enable charting with [Plotly Python Graphing Library](https://plotly.com/python/) (it also supports charting graphs [here](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/)). We already have initial version working in Kusto dashboards, we are working to add it to Kusto web explorer as well as improving its performance (by updating the sandbox version), this should be done in few weeks. Please contact me if you would like to test it now and I can send you the instructions.

Thanks,
Adi